# $k$ regularity in directed graphs

Tags: graph-theory

In this question we will aim to prove that it is NP-hard to decide if a $k$-regular digraph contains a Hamliton cycle for every integer $k\geq 2$. We will achieve this aim by answering the below sub-problems.

Let $u,v_1,v_2$ be distinct vertices in $\overleftrightarrow{K}_{k+1}$ and let $G$ be the digraph by deleting the arcs $v_1u$ and $v_2u$ from $\overleftrightarrow{K}_{k+1}$. That is, $|V(G)|=k+1$ and $xy\in A(G)$ iff $xy\neq v_1u$ and $xy\neq v_2u$.

(a): Prove that $G$ contains a $(u,v_i)$-Hamlilton path for every $i=1,2$ (no matter what $k$ is).

(b): Let $H$ be any 2-regular digraph, and create a new digraph $H^\ast$ by substituting each vertex, $x,$ in $H$ by a copy of $G,$ which we whall name $G_x$. And for each of the two arcs $xy_1,xy_2\in A(H)$ out of a vertex $x$ add an ark from $v_1$ in $G_x$ to $u$ in $G_{y_1}$ and an arc from $v_2$ in $G_x$ to $u$ in $G_{y_2}$. This creates $H^\ast$. Show that $H^\ast$ is a $k-$regular digraph.

See below for an example of the construction of $H^\ast$ when $k=2$ and $H$ is the shown digraph.
[image: picture]

(c): Show that $H^\ast$ is hamiltonian iff $H$ is hamiltonian (no matter what $H$ and $k$ are).

---

I managed to answer (a): so my current problem is (b): and (c):
Can I get any hints to get started with these?